# Using ldid in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cydia

I am trying to use ldid on Xcode 5.0.2 so that I can submit an app to Cydia.  However I keep getting this error:

```
/bin/sh: /Users/Brassfield/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AirHomeVideo-ghxxiyltjhdzmfeibisruvulonjp/Build/Intermediates/AirHomeVideo.build/Debug-iphoneos/AirHomeVideo.build/Script-483D888818903E450087B2EA.sh: /usr/bin/ldid: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I am using what thebigboss.org website has for doing this.

```
ldid for osx is here. You can do this on osx machine or add it as a build step in xcode:
* Under targets, your project, right click and select  Add, new build phase, New run script build phase.
* Type in /usr/bin/ldid -S FULLPATH_TO_YOUR_BINARY
```

What am I doing wrong?  I have Xcode set to NOT require code signing, and just need to use ldid to sign the code to get in Cydia.

Comment: Just bike shedding, but I've had a lot of problems in the past with `ldid`. I found it easier to sign with an iOS developer account; for example: `codesign -fs "Johnny Developer" cryptest.exe` (when building the Crypto++ test harness for a JB iOS device).

Comment: @noloader so to distribute an app on Cydia, I can use a normal Provisioning Profile from Apple to sign the app?

Comment: I'm not sure about that because I don't distribute apps. A quick search of Jailbreak QA did not turn up any results. That might be a good question for the forums.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal, if you type `which ldid` it should show you the correct location of where `ldid` is installed on your machine.  You'll want to replace the `/usr/bin/ldid` in the example to whichever path is given to you.

On my machine, I installed `ldid` through homebrew, so it's on my path as `/usr/local/bin/ldid`.